# Optimizing horizontal addition of columns to meet minumum sums for multiple rows

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Apologies in advance! My math experience only went up to Calc 1 (so long ago) and while I feel like the answer probably exists in countless places across the net I don't know enough terminology and/or a way to word it shortly enough to perform a proper search. Hopefully I can explain this well enough for someone to understand and I'd be sincerely grateful for even a simple link pointing me the right direction. (I have no idea what to even tag this question as.)

---

Given a 'row and column' chart of values I want to find what minimum total of columns that can be horizontally added together to meet minimum values in particular rows.

For Example:

```
___|__cA__cB__
rA |   2   1  
rB |   0   3
```

If I want a minimum of 10 in rB I want a method that returns $4cB$ and $0cA$.

Alternatively if I am looking for a minimum of 10 in rA and 20 in rB I want a method that returns $2cA + 7cB$. This results in a total of 9 columns added, as opposed to the more inefficient solution of simply summing $10cB$ for a total of 10 columns added.

---

Thank you for taking the time to read and sorry if this question is a bit silly. I feel like this is a process I should be able to logic my way through but I have just been drawing a blank or hitting dead ends. A friend with more experience in math suggested this might be matrix 'black magic' but that their understanding doesn't cover that.

For what it is worth I am attempting to implement this in Javascript, in case any particular method of solving this lends itself well to programming.

Comment: This kind of problem is called "linear programming".

Comment: @AlexKruckman My thanks to you for the new vocabulary! I fought with LP solving for a while and how to apply it to my issue before realizing that I was going to be spending too significant a portion of my time on this project trying to grasp/code/debug the solving and found a library to utilize far more cleanly instead. It's sometimes amazing how much simply having a name for something can help.

I'm not sure of the usual processes/etiquette around these sites but if you would like to post this as an answer I would happily flag it as my solution so this isn't left hanging.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I thought this was exactly the sort of question where knowing the right name to search for would help you to figure it out for yourself. Your suggestion is good: I'll turn my comment into an answer so the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: By the way, I think the actual answer to your example problem is $(1\cdot cA + 8\cdot cB)$ or $(2\cdot cA + 7\cdot cB)$, which are equally efficient with $9$ column sums. (Or $(\frac{5}{3})\cdot cA + (\frac{20}{3})\cdot cB$, if you allow non-integer solutions, which gets away with $(\frac{25}{3})$ column sums.) Neither of your suggested solutions $(5\cdot cA + 5\cdot cB)$ and $(20\cdot cA)$ satisfy the requirement of minimum $20$ in row $B$.

Comment: Oh dear... I did completely botch my second example there. I rewrote it a couple times and somewhere along the line I started summing cB instead of rB for some unfathomable reason and attempted to solve the entire thing backwards because of it. I think. Looking at it now I can't be entirely sure what was going through my head beyond being nervous about posting on here! Apologies if that caused any confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problem is called "linear programming".

---

To flesh out my comment into a proper answer:

In your example, you want to add a multiple of column $A$ to a multiple of column $B$. If you add $a$ times column $A$ and $b$ times column $B$, you end up with totals of $2a + b$ in row $A$ and $3b$ in row $B$.

This is called taking a *linear combination* of the column vectors: $$a\begin{bmatrix} 2\\0 \end{bmatrix}+ b\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2a + b\\ 3b\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now your constraints "minimum of $10$ in row $A$" and "minimum of $20$ in row $B$" gives you the inequalities \begin{align*} 2a+b&\geq 10\\ 3b&\geq 20\end{align*}
These inequalities have lots of solutions (like $a = 100$, $b = 42$), but you want the "most efficient one". It seems like "most efficient" in your case means the fewest total number of columns added together. That is, you want to *minimize* the quantity $(a + b)$.

This is exactly a *linear programming* problem: Minimize some function in the variables $a$ and $b$, subject to some inequalities which constrain the values of $a$ and $b$.

Since it seems like you intend the variables $a$ and $b$ to be actual numbers of times you repeatedly add the columns, you might want the additional constraint that $a$ and $b$ have to be natural numbers  (rather than arbitrary real numbers that you scale the columns by). This turns the problem into an *integer linear programming* problem.